# how can I make regexp let go of match of first part when rest does not fit but only fits after next match of first part?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

There is a strange "greedy" behaviour in regexp:
With my search pattern:

```
r'\/begin FUNC\s+(\w*).*?\/begin DEF_VAR\s*([\w .\s]*)\s*\/end DEF_VAR.*?\/end FUNC'
```

With re.S to make '.' match newlines. And the test string being:

```
/begin FUNC
    WDHOL

/end FUNC

/begin FUNC
    AMROTL
    /begin DEF_VAR
        KFMELO
    /end DEF_VAR
/end FUNC
```

The match will return ['WDHOL', 'KFMELO\n\t'] instead of the expected ['AMROTL', 'KFMELO\n\t']. 
How can I make regexp let go of the match for the first part when the first part comes again (or when '/end FUNC')?
I tried negative lookahead, but to no avail. The match returned nothing at all or took just longer with the same result...

Comment: `(\w*)` just get `WDHOL`  `.*?` match  `

/end FUNC

/begin FUNC
    AMROTL
    `, nothing strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
s = '''/begin FUNC
    WDHOL

/end FUNC

/begin FUNC
    AMROTL
    /begin DEF_VAR
        KFMELO
    /end DEF_VAR
/end FUNC'''

pat = re.compile(r'(?:\/begin FUNC)\s+(\w*)(?!.*?\1)\s+\/begin DEF_VAR\s*([\w .\s]*)\s*\/end DEF_VAR.*?\/end FUNC', re.S)

pat.findall(s)
```

Output:

`[('AMROTL', 'KFMELO\n    ')]`

Comment: Thanks. That works even for the extended case that there are more than one words encapsuled in /begin DEF_VAR. I was even able to strip it down and it still worked: '\/begin FUNC\s*(\w*)\s*\/begin DEF_VAR\s*([\w .\s]*)\s*\/end DEF_VAR.*?\/end FUNC'. So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
s = '''
/begin FUNC
    WDHOL

/end FUNC

/begin FUNC
    AMROTL
    /begin DEF_VAR
        KFMELO
    /end DEF_VAR
/end FUNC'''

pat = re.compile('/begin FUNC\s*(\S+)\s*/begin DEF_VAR\s*(\S+)\s*/end DEF_VAR\s*/end FUNC')
result = pat.findall(s, re.DOTALL)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('AMROTL', 'KFMELO')]
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work for my simplified case. However, in the real case (my mistake that I did not specify more detailled), there are more than one words encased in /begin DEF_VAR. But I can easily adapt it with: '/begin FUNC\s*(\S*)\s*/begin DEF_VAR\s*(\w.*)\s*/end DEF_VAR\s*/end FUNC'. So thanks a lot for the help!